# How to change orientation like movie player or media player on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

in my application I need landscape orientation after portrait view or orientation same as when we go to media player default orientation in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override shouldAutorotate:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

This will force your controller to landscape only.

Answer (score 0):

Override the

```
   - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method in the `viewController` that contains the movie player